# multiple sort comments in drupal

Tags: views, comments

like what you can see in this site, I want to have 3 tabs for comments.

oldest first

newest first

sort by likes

I've tested creating views and show in tabs but this way in too heavy!

is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs)

> The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content,
>   specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*. You can
>   create a block on your site containing multiple tabs with
>   corresponding content.

Make 3 view blocks of each, and then create a quick tab of views and enable ajax so the other tabs load only when they get clicked.

Comment: this was my first solution. Making views for comments is too heavy

Comment: oh, I thought you used the views default tab rather than quicktab.

Comment: I guess you could cache your views.

Comment: you are right. it is the last way I think